# How to get value from python class object

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

This is my test code with Regular Expressions / Regex  with python.

```
import re

htmltxt='''
<div>
    <div> name
        <div> samadhi </div>  
    </div>

    <div> age
        <div>28 </div>
    </div>

</div>
'''
opn=re.compile(r'<div')
matches01=opn.finditer(htmltxt)

for m in matches01:
    print(m)
```

result

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(1, 5), match='<div'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(12, 16), match='<div'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(31, 35), match='<div'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(74, 78), match='<div'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(92, 96), match='<div'>
```

how can I access to 'match' variable value from the result object ?

Comment: what are you trying to get exactly? A regex to a HTML file?

Comment: Aaron_ab , I want to get 'match' value.

Comment: This seem to be X-Y issue: you don't really need to use regex to parse HTML... What is your exact desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for m in matches01:
    print(m.group(1))
```

Check out the docs for the `re` module, which explains the `MathObject` class that `finditer()` returns: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject

Comment: Danielle M., it works for me.. 
just use > m.group(0)